# Can Geotools load DEMs?

Tags: java, geotools

This question is hard to answer via Google.  I want to know if someone familiar with GeoTools can let me know whether or not it can read in Digital Elevation Models?  Their website does not list it, but it seems to be a normal, common raster data format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you may take a look to the **gtopo30** plugin:
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/gtopo30.html
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/faq.html

Which is also supported by **GeoServer**:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gtopo30.html

Ref:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_elevation_model

Cheers,
*Carlo Cancellieri*

Answer (score 1):

From the GeoTools [FAQ](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/faq.html):

GeoTools supports additional formats through the use of plug-ins. You can control the  formats supported by your application by only including the plug-ins you requrie.

- arcgrid
- arcsde
- db2
- raster formats

  - geotiff
  - grassraster
  - gtopo30
  - image - world plus image files using common image formats such as JPEG, TIFF, GIF and PNG
  - imageio-ext-gdal (allows access to additional GDAL formats thanks to the ImageIO project)
  - imagemoasaic
  - imagepyramid
  - JP2K
- Database “jdbc-ng” support

  - h2
  - mysql
  - oracle
  - postgis
  - spatialite
  - sqlserver
  - postgis
- property - simple text file format often used for testing
- shapefile

Note the use of [GDAL](http://gdal.org) to import [exotic formats](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) - so if you can't read it in then it's really weird.